# On using CMU Sphinx binaries in Windows 7, how are the executables used?

Tags: cmusphinx

On using CMU Sphinx in Windows 7: There are no instructions or examples for the packaged binaries. I am trying to do an evaluation of sphinx and would like to simply convert an audio file to text for a quick try. There are no examples, How are the executables used?

Answer (score 3):

Pocketsphinx distribution has the following binaries:

- pocketsphinx_batch - used for testing of the recognition on a test database
- pocketsphinx_continuous - used to recognize audio from a microphone

To use pocketsphinx continuous to recognize microphone input use the following from the top folder:

```
bin\Release\pocketsphinx_continuous.exe -hmm  model\hmm\en_US\hub4wsj_sc_8k -lm model\lm\en_US\ehub4.5000.DMP -dict model\lm\en_US\cmu07a.dic
```

To recognize audio from a WAV file in 16khz 16bit mono format:

```
bin\Release\pocketsphinx_continuous.exe -hmm  model\hmm\en_US\hub4wsj_sc_8k -lm model\lm\en_US\ehub4.5000.DMP -dict model\lm\en_US\cmu07a.dic -infile file.wav
```

You should NOT assume that the recognition result will be accurate with this command.

CMUSphinx is a complex software which is not easy to evaluate at the moment. You definitely shouldn't assume that there is a quick and easy way to test it properly. Most likely with 5-minute test you will come to a conclusion it doesn't work.

You need to understand basics of the speech recognition in order to apply CMUSphinx. To begin, at least read the tutorial

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorial

A proper evaluation require the following things:

- You need to collect a representative set describing your data
- You need to find out what accuracy does default generic setup provide on your test data
- You need to understand accuracy issues and try to fix them

To get help on CMUSphinx, it's worth to ask about the problems on forum. You need to provide a test dataset in order to get help on the accuracy/performance.

Comment: Thanks for you help and quick response. It did work on first try and I am surprised and happy with the results. Once I adjust it with a good data set like you suggest it should be even better.  I will look at all of your ideas.
Thanks, Frank